# Drop down menu with img-dropdown-content display: none; not working as expected

Tags: html, css

Drop down menu with img-dropdown-content display: none; not working, might be overridden by something - html and css only

I have tried using visibility: hidden; with and without !important and also display: none; with !important to override possible attributes of the div from the html code but it didn't work. Please note that I have just started coding in html and css so please bear with me if I have some formatting problems :). This is also not meant to be a serious public webpage, but instead I just have it running locally on my own Windows PC using python -m http.server in the Windows PowerShell so I can test the code I wrote and learn a bit about website design.

```css
.dropbtn {
  border: black 1px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  display: none !important;
  visibility: hidden !important;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 style='font-family:Coda;' class='title'>Content Distributor</h1>
</header>

<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn"><img src=images/menu.ico></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="stores.html">Stores</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- <a href='stores.html' class='button'><button type="button" class="button">Stores</button></a> -->
```

Comment: I tried to figure out what the question was to make a better title. I also made you a snippet. Why do you have a header tag before the body tag? That is invalid HTML right there. Please elaborate on expected and actual output

Comment: @mplungjan I tried to create a dropdown menu using an icon as button but the link to the "store.html" is not hidden by default. Also, the css is just the part about the menu, those are not all the lines in the file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working snippet:

```css
.dropbtn {
  border: black 1px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 style='font-family:Coda;' class='title'>Content Distributor</h1>
</header>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn"><img src=images/menu.ico></button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="stores.html">Stores</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- <a href='stores.html' class='button'><button type="button" class="button">Stores</button></a> -->
```

And also note that you are using `.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content`, by using this selector the `.dropdown-content` will become visible when you hover over `.dropdown` div, But if you want to show the dropdown when the `.dropbtn` is hovered change it to this: `.dropbtn:hover .dropdown-content`

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot! Though, when I run the snippet in here, it absolutely works but in my script it doesn't anymore.

Comment: Which script? You didn't mention any script in your question. Please provide it.

Comment: not really script but the python http server, in the html and css file in the directory of the server

Comment: You are confusing me... You don't need a python http server, you can just test it locally by double click on the html file.

Comment: I know I don't need to have it on a server, it still doesn't work when I double click it either, which is what I would expect as I access the same file, no matter if I use the server or double click it. The server does not have a public ip or domain either, its just localhost:8000

Comment: Can you more specifically tell why it is not working? Did you save the file after editing?

Comment: I could not see any changes in the css file, in the html it was similar but the indents were different. On the page, I have the icon but nothing happens when I hove over it. The content is hidden now though so that issue is fixed.

Comment: I think you have to restart your python server because maybe it didn't update the file. Or you can try hard reloading the page.

Comment: Neither helps, it seems like there is an issue with the button itself or the line <button class="dropbtn"><img src=images/menu.ico></button> as it only displays the image but not as a button. Maybe it also has an issue in the css file as it doesn't even show the border added in the .dropbtn{}.

Comment: Does something happen if you hover over it?

Comment: No, it is just the image and it looks and acts as if it would not be in a <button></button>

Comment: I can't figure it out

Comment: Thank you for the help with the content though, I will find a solution sometime :)

Comment: Yeah, Its my pleasure too :).